# Angular: angular-resizable-element library validate question

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi i cannot read the scope variables in the Validate function and i cannot find any documentation about it, do you have any solutions?

```
  export class StepComponent   {    
    maxwidth = 500;

    onResizeEnd(event: ResizeEvent): void {
        console.log(this.maxwidth); // it works
    }

    validate(event: ResizeEvent): boolean {                  
        console.log(this.maxwidth); // undefined            
        if (event.rectangle.width > this.maxwidth) {            
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}

<div mwlResizable [enableGhostResize]="true"
    [validateResize]="validate"
    (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is printing `undefined`, because it is trying to find `maxWidth` property within the `Resizeable` Directive. You need to send the proper scope of `current` object (`StepComponent`) to the Directive input.

This should work `[validateResize]="validate.bind(this)"`

```
<div mwlResizable [enableGhostResize]="true"
    [validateResize]="validate.bind(this)"
    (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)">
</div>
```